# Generated asp.net button placed in .cs file event not firing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Good Evening

My dynamically created asp buttons that will handle a data rows editing and deletion will not fire the event.

I'm displaying a table in my aspx page using the html.append action and then putting that into a placeholder which I have added to the aspx page like so:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
    {            
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();

        if (!(ConnectMysql()))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Failed to Connect to Database!');", true);
        }       
    }
    CreateObjs();
    GenerateHtmlTable();             
}
```

Here is my method to generate the table

```
 private void GenerateHtmlTable()
{
    otblUsers.SelectAll();
    DataTable dt = otblUsers.DefaultView.ToTable();
    //Building an HTML string.
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    //Table start.               
    html.Append("<thead>");
    //Building the Header row.
    html.Append("<tr>");
    int j = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<th>");
        html.Append(column.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</th>");
        j++;
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");
    html.Append("</thead>");

    html.Append("<tbody>");      
    //Building the Data rows.
    int rowcnt = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        rowcnt++;
        html.Append("<tr>");
        int k = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            k++;
            html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                if (j == k) //place button before next row                
                {

                    html.Append("<div class=\"pull-right\"><asp:Button ID = \"btnEdit\" class=\"btn btn-mini\" runat= \"server\"  OnClick=\"btnEdit_Click\"  OnServerClick=\"btnedit_ServerClick\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i>Edit</button></div>");
                    html.Append(" <div class=\"pull-right\"><asp:Button ID = \"btnDelete\" class=\"btn btn-mini\" runat= \"server\"  OnServerClick=\"btnedit_ServerClick\" OnClick=\"btnEdit_Click\" Type=\"submit\"><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>Delete</button></div>");
                } html.Append("</td>");
        }            
        html.Append("</tr>");
    }

    html.Append("</tbody>");        
    //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

and here are the test events that won't fire:

```
protected void btnedit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Console.Write("1212");    
}
protected void  btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("sdfsd");
}
```

and this is how I add the placeholder into the aspx page :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

I only have one row of data now for testing purposes.I do realize that I need to create the asp buttons dynamically with unique names and ids for each row.

How do I get the event to fire?I'm a WinForms developer and I know this could be down to inexperience and possibly something about session refreshing?

Comment: Simply adding `runat="server"` to some HTML doesn't make it run on the server. You can't just stick that in a string and embed it in the page and expect it to work. Instead of dynamically building HTML, why don't you use a GridView or Repeater and data bind to it?

Comment: I went with a html table because of the css styles that apply to the table.The site is bootstrap and looks very nice so didnt want to break that styling.I can use a gridview but then it wouldnt look nice.This is the template im using. http://themedesigner.in/demo/matrix-admin/tables.html

Comment: You can use a Repeater and still get all the benefits you mention.